# Backbone Not Firing Events

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

So here is an example of my app in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GWXpn/1/

The problem is click event isn't being fired at all. I am not getting any JS errors in the console.

First, I wanted to display an unordered list with couple if items, each item should be clickable. This is what I did:

```
var FooModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'ul', // name of (orphan) root tag in this.el
        initialize: function() {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render'); // every function that uses 'this' as the current object should be in here
        },
        render: function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                var view = new SingleView({
                    model: new FooModel()
                });
                $(this.el).append(view.render().el);
            }
            return this; // for chainable calls, like .render().el
        }
    });

      var SingleView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'li', // name of (orphan) root tag in this.el
        initialize: function() {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'click'); // every function that uses 'this' as the current object should be in here
        },
        events: {
            "click": "click"
        },
        click: function(ev) {
            console.log("aaa");
            alert(333);

        },
        render: function() {
            $(this.el).append("aaa");
            return this; // for chainable calls, like .render().el
        }
    });
```

I wanted to divide my app in to multiple modules (header, body, footer) so I created an abstract model and extended my modules from it:

```
var AbstractModule = Backbone.Model.extend({
    getContent: function () {
        return "TODO";
    },
    render: function () {
        return $('<div></div>').append(this.getContent());
    }
});
var HeaderModule = AbstractModule.extend({
    id: "header-module",
});
var BodyModule = AbstractModule.extend({
    id: "body-module",
    getContent: function () {

        var listView = new ListView();

        return $("<div/>").append($(listView.render().el).clone()).html();
    }
});
var ModuleCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: AbstractModule,
});
```

Then I just created my main view and rendered all its subviews:

```
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#hello'),
    initialize: function (modules) {
        this.moduleCollection = new ModuleCollection();
        for (var i = 0; i < modules.length; i++) {
            this.moduleCollection.add(new modules[i]);
        }
    },
    render: function () {
        var self = this;
        _(this.moduleCollection.models).each(function (module) { // in case collection is not empty
            $(self.el).append(module.render());
        }, this);
    }
});

var appView = new AppView([HeaderModule, BodyModule]);
appView.render();
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: The click fires an alert for me. Also, your fiddle has javascript in the css pane.

Comment: @Prisoner Sorry I posted wrong jsfiddle link. I fixed it now...

Comment: This seems to be a problem related to the Backbone's version you're using (0.3.3 seriously?). I highly doubt anyone will be able to help you as things are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two bugs in one line:

```
return $("<div/>").append($(listView.render().el).clone()).html();
```

First of all, [`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) doesn't copy the events unless you explicitly ask for them:

> Normally, any event handlers bound to the original element are not copied to the clone. The optional `withDataAndEvents` parameter allows us to change this behavior, and to instead make copies of all of the event handlers as well, bound to the new copy of the element.
>   [...]
>   As of jQuery 1.5, `withDataAndEvents` can be optionally enhanced with `deepWithDataAndEvents`  to copy the events and data for all children of the cloned element.

You're cloning the `<ul>` here so you'll want to set both of those flags to `true`.

Also, [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) returns a string and strings don't have events so you're doubling down on your event killing.

I don't understand why you're cloning anything at all, you should just return the `el` and be done with it:

```
    return listView.render().el;
```

If you insist on cloning, then you'd want something like this:

```
    return $(listView.render().el).clone(true, true);
```

but that's just pointless busy work.

BTW, `'title'` and `'Title'` are different model attributes so you'll want to say:

```
console.log(this.model.get("title") + " clicked");
```

instead of

```
console.log(this.model.get("Title") + " clicked");
```

Also, Backbone collections have a lot of [Underscore methods mixed in](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) so don't mess with a collection's `models` directly, where you're currently saying:

```
_(this.moduleCollection.models).each(...)
```

just say:

```
this.moduleCollection.each(...)
```

And as Loamhoof mentions, 0.3.3 is ancient history, please upgrade to newer versions of Backbone, Underscore, and jQuery. You should also read the change logs so that you can use newer features (such as `this.$el` instead of `$(this.el)`, fewer `_.bindAll` calls, `listenTo`, ...).

Partially Corrected Demo (including updated libraries): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/e4Pba/

I also ripped out the `alert` call, that's a hateful debugging technique that can cause a huge mess if you get into accidental infinite loops and such, `console.log` is much friendlier.